# Action buttons in notification are showing but when pressed not working

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a service to start the mediaplayer as soon as the notification is shown and then stop the service when the action button is pressed. The service starts fine. But the service doesn't stop on clicking the action button.

This is my notification builder

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder getReminderNotification(String title,String message,PendingIntent intent1){

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),reminderChannelID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_medicine)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back,"OK",intent1);
}

public void cancelNotification() {
   NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(1); // Notification ID to cancel
}

public void startMyService(){
    startService(new Intent(this, TimerService.class));
}

public void stopMyService(){
    stopService(new Intent(this,TimerService.class));
}
```

This is my reminder receiver:

```
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context,DismissReminderReceiver.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("action","stop");
    PendingIntent intent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,newIntent,0);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String title=extras.getString("title");
    String message=extras.getString("message");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = notificationHelper.getReminderNotification(title, message,intent1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),TimerService.class));
        }else {
            notificationHelper.startMyService();
        }
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, builder.build());

}}
```

This is my code to dismiss the notification

```
public class DismissReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Here");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String action = extras.getString("action");
    System.out.println(action);
    if (action.equals("stop")) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        notificationHelper.stopMyService();
        notificationHelper.cancelNotification();
    }
}}
```

And this is my service:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

public Context context = this;
public Handler handler = null;
public Runnable runnable = null;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;public TimerService(){}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
System.out.println("Service Started");
    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}}
```

Comment: How are you building `PendingIntent intent1` in the first code snippet (the code that shows a notification)?

Comment: check the second code snippet. I have created pending intent in onReceive() method and passed it as a parameter

Comment: Does DismissReceiver get the broadcast? I'm trying to break down the problem into two parts - the receiver (1) and the service (2).

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev No it doesn't :(
I don't know why but the DissmissReceiver doesn't get the broadcast.

Comment: I'd say try giving an action to     Intent newIntent = new Intent(context,DismissReminderReceiver.class); I mean not an "action" Extra which you already have, but a real action.

Comment: I also don't see where  you register the receiver - if you're doing it in the manifest, make sure it's there with a matching action (and the receiver  stanza is there to begin with).

Comment: You just saved my ass right there. Forgot to register the receiver in the manifest file. Spend the whole night scratching my head. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't see where you register the receiver - if you're doing it in the manifest, make sure it's there with a matching action (and the receiver stanza is there to begin with).