# Send data from Broadcast Receiver to running Service

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I require a service to send messages to the Cloud while receiving data from the device as a result I have the following code:

```
public class MessageService extends Service {
  private int mAlert = 0;
  private PanicReceiver mPanicReceiver;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mPanicReceiver = new PanicReceiver();

    IntentFilter panicFilter = new IntentFilter();
    panicFilter.addAction(Constants.PANIC_ON_RECEIVER_ACTION);
    panicFilter.addAction(Constants.PANIC_OFF_RECEIVER_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(mPanicReceiver, panicFilter);

  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mPanicReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private class PanicReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case Constants.PANIC_ON_RECEIVER_ACTION:
          mAlert = 2;
          break;
        case Constants.PANIC_OFF_RECEIVER_ACTION:
          mAlert = 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to seperate the broadcast receiver to a seperate file. How can you do that?

Comment: Check the ReminderReceiver and TimeService in this post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962843/action-buttons-in-notification-are-showing-but-when-pressed-not-working>

Answer (score 1):

MessageService.class

```
public class MessageService extends Service {

  private PanicReceiver mPanicReceiver;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  mPanicReceiver = new PanicReceiver();

  IntentFilter panicFilter = new IntentFilter();
  panicFilter.addAction(Constants.PANIC_ON_RECEIVER_ACTION);
  panicFilter.addAction(Constants.PANIC_OFF_RECEIVER_ACTION);

  registerReceiver(mPanicReceiver, panicFilter);

  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mPanicReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private int getAlert() {
    return mPanicReceiver.getAlert();
  }
}
```

PanicReceiver.java

```
private class PanicReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private int mAlert = 0;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
      case Constants.PANIC_ON_RECEIVER_ACTION:
        this.setAlert(2);
        break;
      case Constants.PANIC_OFF_RECEIVER_ACTION:
        this.setAlert(0);
        break;
    }
  }

  public int getAlert() {
    return mAlert;
  }

  public void setAlert(int mAlert) {
    this.mAlert = mAlert;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `mAlert` from MessageService to PanicReceiver, than you can use the IDE to assist you to refactor out the class pressing F6 with the cursor upside the class name, or with a right click:

[image: Right click]

[image: Refactor popup]

Comment: So how does my Receiver update mAlert in MessageService while it is running?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to achieve. If you want to move the receiver out and still be notified in the service class when a message arrives, you can use a callback on the receiver constructor.